# Shopify gem: is there a way to retrieve the terms of service for a store?

Tags: shopify

I took a look at [the documentation page](http://api.shopify.com/shop.html), but it looks like the terms of service doesn't come back when you load up a store through the API. Is it possible to retrieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is now a [Policies API](https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/policy) that you can use to retrieve the store terms of service and [other policies.](https://help.shopify.com/manual/sell-online/checkout-settings/refund-privacy-tos)

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there’s no API endpoint for this.